# no job control in this shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Quick question regarding this error in Bash.  I have some bash scripts that I run at work on some servers. We have been trying to implement Rundeck as a way to automate.  When I call these scripts through Rundeck I get the error bash: no job control in this shell.  Now I am new to linux and shell scripting but what I have figured is this is due to interactivity of the shell. The scripts I am calling will call other scripts (perl and shell) as part of their operation. But since I am not logged on in a terminal, they can't do this and fail. That is the best understanding I have.

I have tried adding a -l to my #!/bin/bash in my script I send through Rundeck. I have also tried to utilize the ad-hoc command option through Rundeck and run the jobs individually.  Still not luck.  I thought perhaps it was a pathing issue so I tired setting the path PATH=$PATH  but no change.

Basically I need to allow these scripts to open their subprocesses. So the question is, how I modify how I call these scripts so they have full control?  Is that possible? Sorry if this lacks info, I just don't know how properly put it out there. let me know what other info is needed. Thanks

Edit: Some code snips on where the message comes in:

```
system "pntadm -R $Net >/dev/null 2>&1";
system "pntadm -C $Net $BUILD{$Net}{netmask} $MYip";
```

Comment: You don't need job control to run other processes, what part of your script causes that error?

Comment: In terms of "what other information is needed" -- what we need here is a [mcve]: The smallest possible code sample someone else can run to see the same error. Job control is only enabled in interactive shells by default, but you don't actually **need** it if you're doing things the best-practices way (ie. capturing background processes' PIDs and interacting with them by PID rather than by jobspec). Thus, if you have a noninteractive script that says it needs job control, that script should be fixed; but we can't tell you how to fix it until you've shown a sample sufficient to cause the error.

Comment: I have updated with a snip of script.  Problem is, this is internal and quite a bit can't be shared.  But when run from the terminal there is no issues, only when remotely called from Rundeck.  So in the snip we are updating DCHP.  The make the pntadm call and it goes bad there.  On my other script they reference a call to some perl modules and it fails there.  Does that help out?